# Contact form 7 submits form when pressing enter/return key

Tags: contact-form-7

I have been searching for an answer with no luck so far and I'm no code expert, so there are some things that may have a solution but I simply son't get them.
Contact Form 7 Form on my new website has 2 issues I want to check and solve:

1. When hitting Enter/Return key the form is automatically sent so if a person is typing a message, they cannot continue writing.
2. There's no way I can make the text area look higher or have multiple lines so the person sending a message can hit the enter/return key to continue writing in the next line.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is by using the *textarea* shortcode

Textarea: 
Both textarea and textarea* are for a multi-line input and accept any form of text. textarea* is a required field.

**Example:**

```
[textarea your-message 40x10 "your message here ..."]
```

Source: https://contactform7.com/text-fields/

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the exact code I used, yet I still get just one line and no option to hit Enter/return without sending the form immediately

Comment: Have you tried to hit Enter while pressing Shift key?

Comment: It doesn't work. Even if it did, how would I let people know about it?

Comment: It´s weird, there is no such error in mine using that shortcode. It might be related to your theme. Have you tried to check it?  Maybe css code need to be added.